# Qt Linguist: swap the native language of the sources with a translation?

Tags: c++, qt, internationalization, qt-linguist

Let's say that a long time ago I began a project which wasn't supposed to be shared or translated. To make it simple all strings and GUI were in my native language in the code, in French.

Then the project became more and more important so that several translations are now available.

The problem is that all translations start from the French strings in the code. For the guy speaking XXX and willing to translate the software into XXX, using Qt Linguist implies opening 2 files:

- the translation from French to English,
- the translation from French to XXX.

This way it is possible to translate from English to XXX.

Is there a tool somewhere that could replace all French strings of the sources with their corresponding English translation? Another tool that would change all .ts files so that they are not translating French anymore but English?

Answer (score 0):

If you open 2 files at the same time with Qt Linguist you will see translations for both. So if you provide the complete translation from French to English, and the incomplete translation from French to XXX, your translator only need to open the 2 files at once.